# React Firebase store doesn't save zip

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to save zip file which is uploaded by user. I read the instructions about Firebase and I used what firebase instruction says but when I check the storage, name as undefined file is saved but file type is shown as zip. My code which is used while file is being uploaded, is shown below:

```
let reader = new FileReader()
    var loads = [];
    reader.onload = (function (f) {
        return function (e) {
            var data = this.result; 

            loads.push({
                data: data
            });
            console.log(loads)
        };
    });
    var file = new Blob(loads)

    var metadata = {
        contentType: 'application/zip'
    };

    var uploadTask = storage.ref().child('CodeHomeworks/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

    uploadTask.on(Firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,  
        function (snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case Firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED:  
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case Firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING:  
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
        }, function (error) { 
        }, function () { 
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you able to store another kind of files into Firestore (images, video, txt files) via this code? Do the variables used to read the content from the users have actual content?

Comment: @KevinQuinzel I can store only images. Yes variables are used to read contents.